# How to Reject Get method when QueryString is passed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url.action, urlrewriting.net

In MVC application My Current Route Config is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PaymentInformation",
    "PaymentInformation.aspx/{resNum}",
    new { controller = "Reservation", action = "Edit", resNum = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

It calls below mentioned method when we hit this Url: `https://www.example.com/PaymentInformation.aspx`

```
HttpGet]
[ValidateRequest(true)]
public ActionResult Edit(string resNum)
{
    ReservationPresenter reservationPresenter = new ReservationPresenter();
    return View(reservationPresenter);
}
```

What I want is that when Querystring is passed (in GET Method) then **the same above method/Action above should not be called** and I just want to Show a Message.

The URL with Querystring should be like this: `https://www.example.com/PaymentInformation.aspx?xyz`

**Can please anyone suggest me what will be MapRoute in Route Config.**

In breif what we want is that Any request with sensitive information sent over a GET method should be rejected by the application.

Comment: If you don't want the method to be hit, remove `{resNum}` from the route and make the method `public ActionResult Edit()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the way you should go, but if it's really what you want, try the following:

1) Create a IRouteConstraint class and implement it, something like this:

```
public class NonQueryStringRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint {
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {
        return httpContext.Request.QueryString.Count == 0;
    }
}
```

2) Add the constraint to the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PaymentInformation",
    "PaymentInformation.aspx/{resNum}",
    new { controller = "Reservation", action = "Edit", resNum = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { resNum = new NonQueryStringRouteConstraint() }
);
```

Mind you though, the NonQueryStringRouteConstraint will also be executed when generating URL's, so you might want to check the `routeDirection` parameter if necessary.